# How to check if a user input is equal to a randomly generated element's value from a list in php?

Tags: php, html, server

So here is my problem: [image: Quiz Problem]

And I am not sure why my code is not working. What it is doing now is it's checking the user input to the next randomly generated city to country instead of checking it to the current one. Here is my PHP file so far: 
[LINK TO WEBPAGE](https://php-project-developertenzin.c9users.io/capital_quiz.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php
        $cityToCountry = array();
        $file = fopen('world_capitals.txt', 'r');
        while ( !feof($file) )
        {
            $line = fgets($file, 2048);
            $delimiter = "\t";
            $data = str_getcsv($line, $delimiter);
            $cityToCountry[$data[0]] = $data[1];
        }  
        fclose($file);
        /*
        foreach($cityToCountry as $key => $value) {
            echo "$key is at $value<br>";
        }
        */
        $randomCity = array_rand($cityToCountry);

        echo $randomCity . " is the capital city of what country?<br><br>";


    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="data"/> 
        <input type="submit" name="check" value="check"/>
    </form>

    <?php
     if (isset($_POST['check'])) {
            $input = $_POST["data"];
            echo $input . "<br>";
            echo $randomCity . "<br>";

            if ($input == $cityToCountry[$randomCity]) {
                echo "Correct";
            } else {
                echo "False";
            }

        }


    ?>

</html>
```

It gives giving "False" result. What am I doing wrong here? Have been stuck on this for hours. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you paste the values of `$cityToCountry` and `$randomCity` ? Need to be certain `$randomCity` isset in `$cityToCountry`

Answer (score 1):

When the script receives the data from the form the variable **$randomCity** has changed again because it's executed from the top. It's comparing with a different city!

You should send a "hidden" field with the info of the original city.

```
<form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="data"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo $randomCity;?>"/> 
        <input type="submit" name="check" value="check"/>
</form>
```

and, then, replace in your check function the **$randomCity** with the sent data **$_POST["city"]**

Comment: Wow! What a nice solution! I never knew the input type hidden even existed... Anyway, I have one slight problem now. When I click on check, it asks a different question at the top every time. How would I keep track of the initial question and not change the question when they hit on "check".

Comment: Maybe the solution is to check first if there is a "city" data sent from the form or not with an if... else statement. 

if(!isset($_POST["city"])) (if there is no city data) the top of your code should be the same but, if the $_POST["city"] var contains data, you can print it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check your if statement ,there are compare the value of city to capital,

```
if ($input == $cityToCountry[$randomCity]) {
                echo "Correct";
            } else {
                echo "False";
            }
```

Comment: It was not a problem with the if statement, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your if statement

```
if ($input == $randomCity) 
        {
              echo "Correct";
        } 
        else 
       {
             echo "False";
       }
```

Comment: That logic doesn't make sense. I have to compare the user's input to the country of the $randomCity, not the $randomCity itself.